# Vertex groups can not be named in blender 2.70

Tags: interface

For some reason the name text field doesn't appear for vertex groups in blender 2.70. I tried in 2.69 and it's there and works fine. Was this feature removed in 2.70 or am I missing something?

Comment: I was having the same problem until I found this post. A double-LMB does not work for me. Ctrl+LMB does work, and I can certainly live with that. I have run into the double-click problem before, however. That case was with "The Room." That turned out to be caused by a developer-affirmed problem. The program was ported to Windows from Mac, and it did not use the operating system to distinguish a double-click from two single-clicks. I should have noted that, as we get older (I'm 76), often our reaction time gets slower. That lengthens the time between the clicks of a double-click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> click, or double <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> click on the name of the vertex group. That is now how to rename anything in that type of list.

[youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAokd6h-Rgk)

Comment: Double click also works.

Comment: Triple click works, double click don't work.

Comment: @Gonzou what system and mouse are you using, because double click does work for me.

Comment: @David, you're right. I checked the tooltip and it says: 'double click to rename'. But in my case it's not working. I use Windows 7 and the standard mouse. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: @Gonzou I do not know what is wrong. You could ask a new question.